# gcloud ml-engine with python3.5 tkinter import error on run

Tags: python-3.x, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to run my model on Google cloud ml-engine with:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $NAME --module-name train.task_w2v \
     --package-path train --runtime-version 1.8 --python-version 3.5 \
     --scale-tier BASIC --staging-bucket $BUCKET --region $REGION
```

And this is my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['numpy', 'tensorflow', 'pandas', 'matplotlib',
'opencv-python', 'PyYAML', 'coloredlogs', 'scikit-learn', 'scipy', 'matplotlib']

setup(
    name='ConvMultiAttention',
    version='0.9',
    author='name',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
)
```

The model runs fine locally and gets successfully build:

> I  master-replica-0 Successfully installed model-0.9 coloredlogs-10.0 cycler-0.10.0 humanfriendly-4.15.1 kiwisolver-1.0.1 matplotlib-2.2.2 opencv-python-3.4.1.15 pyparsing-2.2.0 master-replica-0
>
> I  master-replica-0 Running command: python3 -m train.task_w2v master-replica-0

But then it gets this exception:

> master-replica-0 Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in  import _tkinter ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'
>
> master-replica-0 Command '['python3', '-m', 'train.task_w2v']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Since my understanding is that tkinter is part of python3.5 I don't really know what goes wrong here, or what to do. I tried to run it without matplotlib and with a lower tf version, but the problems consisted.

Also I get these warnings:

> google-cloud-spanner 0.29.0 has requirement requests<3.0dev,>=2.18.4, but you'll have requests 2.13.0 which is incompatible.
>
> The script humanfriendly is installed in '/root/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.

Which I don't really know how to handle, or if I even need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using TK on a headless training job is not going to be very beneficial. As noted by user2368505 in the comments, the following should avoid using TK:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("agg")
```

In case it's beneficial for posterity, I found that on my own local Ubuntu VM, tkinter was not installed. If desired, one could add the following to your `setup.py:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(['apt-get', '-y', 'install', 'python3-tk'])
```

Again, not directly useful, but serves to show how one can arbitrary install dependencies via `setup.py`.

Comment: I don't have permission to do that on the gcloud ml-engine. I got around it by using:
"import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt",
since I don't use tkinter. If there is a way to make an apt-get subprocess call on the ml-engine could you add it to your answer so I can accept it for other people?

Comment: I believe the apt-get command will work (i.e. you should have permission). There's a chance you need `sudo` first. Also, I've updated my answer with the `agg` backend.